# Stranger error with the .join function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to write a program which finds the roots of an inputted mathematical function. I've only just started, so what I show here is only the start, and there are unused variables.

Here I wrote a function which is supposed to replace the term 'x' in a function with a value you input, say, 100. Here is the code:

```
code = list(input("Enter mathematical function: "))
lowBound = int(input("Enter lower bound: "))
upBound = int(input("Enter upper bound: "))

def plugin(myList, value):
  for i in range(len(myList)):
    if myList[i] == 'x':
      myList[i] = value #replaces x with the inputted value
  return ''.join(myList) #supposed to turn the list of characters back into a string

print(plugin(code,upBound))
```

But when I run the program, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 11, in <module>
File "python", line 9, in plugin
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

(I'm using an online programming platform, so the file is just called 'python')

This doesn't make any sense to me. myList should not be an int, and even if it was the right data type (str), it should be a list. Can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: `upBound` is an integer, you put that into the list. You can't use `str.join()` to join anything other than string values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing a str type (or character) with an int type.

Try this instead:

```
myList[i] = str(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only join an iterable of strings

```
return ''.join(str(x) for x in myList)
```

Or, more succinctly. Remove the function

```
print(''.join(str(upBound if x =='x' else x) for x in code)
```